# Add tag for [query]

Tags: feature-request, tags

I've occasionally noticed tags about SQL queries with the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag. Most recently this was [i have probleam in compare count two tabel in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73428117/i-have-probleam-in-compare-count-two-tabel-in-mysql#73428117). I think this is because when you type "query" into the tag line, the first completion is "jquery".

We should add an explicit tag for "query" to make this less likely.

There's a tag [sql-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-query), which is a synonym for [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql). But if you've already selected the "sql" tag, it won't appear in the completions for "query" since it would be a duplicate.

Or is there some way to make "jquery" less likely to appear first in the completion results? I think people just don't notice the 1-letter difference.

Comment: Is the purpose only for SQL queries? How about other possible usages? Are you sure this tag won't be misused?

Comment: some of the other uses have their own tags and may show up in the completions.

Comment: Well, based on testing the ask question page, the shown tags are the most popular. So unless the [query] tag has more counts than the current [jquery] tag, then it won't be shown anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think adding this tag would achieve anything useful.

Whether mistyped or not, tagging an SQL question with "query" doesn't really add any information. It's more like keyword-stuffing (as used somewhere like Instagram) than categorisation (as tags are intended here).

If I saw a question tagged [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query) I'd probably edit it to remove the second tag anyway, which is exactly the same amount as effort as removing the accidental [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), so nothing is gained.

The real solution would be an overhaul of the tag editing UI, which on desktop shows a pop-up of the description as you type each tag, but evidently not in a way that users notice. Until that is fixed (and a solution added for mobile users), there will always be tags which are added accidentally, and the solution will remain to simply edit them on sight.

Comment: Redundant tags don't add information, but they aren't misleading like wrong tags. So while this might not be the perfects solution, it may be better than the existing situation.

Comment: @Barmar What exactly is the cost of a "misleading" tag? I can't imagine there are many questions where you actually read the question differently because of that tag, unless the text of the question is so confusing that you genuinely don't know which technology was meant.

Comment: Misleading tags will cause it to show up in inappropriate search results.

Comment: @Barmar OK, so you're watching the [tag:jquery] tag, or searching for something in it, and an SQL question shows up in your results; you might waste a few seconds clicking through before realising it's mistagged; if you have enough rep, you might take a few more seconds clicking "edit tags" and fixing it. Then you'll get back to your search. That seems like a pretty low cost, and not really worth changing the tagging policy of the site to avoid.